# keep subtree and main repo in sync

Tags: git, github

I have a big multi-module Maven project where I would like to keep the modules as subtrees which are in sync with the main repo.

For example, I have a got repo at https://github.com/coderplus/copy-rename-maven-plugin/

I have created a subtree using

```
git subtree split -P src -b src-only
```

and then pulled this subtree into another repo and pushed it to github

```
git pull D:\copy-rename-maven-plugin src-only
git remote add origin https://github.com/coderplus/test-git.git
git push origin -u master
```

Is there any way to keep both these GitHub repos in sync?

repo1 - https://github.com/coderplus/copy-rename-maven-plugin/

repo2 - https://github.com/coderplus/test-git

in such a way that anything pushed to repo1 is pushed to repo2 and vice versa?

Comment: You can use `git pre-push hook` to implement that.

Comment: thanks Allen, can you let me know what kind of git commands should I use in the pre-push hook to set up a 2-way sync.